# how to create a Proxy for accessing OData Service on android

Tags: android, odata

I'm new to android and i am following [this tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/uruit/archive/2011/09/13/accessing-odata-from-android-using-restlet.aspx) to access an OData service on android.
I am stuck where I have to make a proxy to access the Odata service. can anyone tell me how to make a proxy?
the tutorial says to develop it using:

IDataServiceProxy proxy = new DataServiceAtomPubProxyImpl(DataServiceClient.URL);

i have tried to include it in my MainActivity.java but it is not working. Can you tell me where are these classes defined: IDataServiceProxy, DataServiceAtomPubProxyImpl , DataServiceClient. ? and how to proceed on with making a proxy for my android app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example does not explain this, but it is actually quite simple:

If you look into the files you imported from the java-project, you should have one file named something like: "*MyData***OdataAppService.java**". This is your service, not the other files you see in the example.

To get the service you simply create a new instance of this:

**MyDataOdataAppService service = new MyDataOdataAppService ();**

... then you can run service.createMyItemQuery("............");